# General Binomial Expansion

Tags: binomial-theorem

I have two operators $A$ and $B$ that do not commute, thus the binomial expansion can't be used. Is there any general formula for $(A+B)^n$, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Thank you.

Comment: In other words, your saying that if, for example, $V$ is a finite-dimensional $F$-vector space, and if $A,B\in\mathcal{L}(V,V)$ are commuting operators, then the binomial expansion for the aforementioned operators is valid to use? I figured so, as I used this statement in another proof for a homework problem, and I was trying to find out if that is a valid argument to use?

Comment: For the sake of brevity, the homework problem I proved follows. Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-vector space, and then let $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,V)$ where $D\in\mathcal{L}(V,V)$ is the diagonalizable part of $T$. Then, if $g\in\mathbb{C}[x]$, we have the diagonalizable part of $g(T)$ is $g(D)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Will wrote in his since-deleted answer. it's the sum of all the $2^n$ words of length $n$ over the alphabet $A,B$. You won't get a simpler answer, unless you know something useful about $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you will find this useful, but I think the best you can do is:
$$
(A+B)^n = \sum_{f:\{1,\dotsc, n\}\to \{A, B\}} f(1)f(2)\dotsb f(n)
$$
The sum is over all functions from the set $\{1,\dotsc,n\}$ to the set $\{A, B\}$.

When $A$ and $B$ commute, the coefficient of $A^kB^{n-k}$ is the number of such functions which take the value $A$ $k$ times and take the value $B$ $n-k$ times, giving the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 0):

If the variables $A$ and $B$ are free (they have *no* relations), then the expansion of $(A + B)^n$ has $2^n$ terms.  They are all $n$-letter words in the alphabet $\{A, B\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for replying. In conclusion, the answer to my question would be a no. Unless of course, there is some other info on $A$ and $B$.